# How to validate values in property?

Tags: c#, oop, validation, properties

I have a question. How can i validate my price in property to be positive number, else to throw a new exception.

I have already tried it that way, but still doesn't work:

```
public decimal Price
{
    get
    {
        { return this.price; }
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.price < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The price should be positive!");
        }
        else
        {
            this.price = value;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I mean that, when I am giving a negative number for price value, the property doesn't catch the exception.

Comment: change **this.price** with the **value** in your if statement.

Answer (score 4):

Now i see, you are checking against the backing field in the setter of the property which has the last value or the default value `0` if it was not yet initialized.  Use the [`value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1khb4f8.aspx) instead:

```
private decimal price;
public decimal Price
{
    get
    {
        { return this.price; }
    }
    set
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The price should be positive!");
        }
        else
        {
            this.price = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even that way, when I change the price with value in if statement, still doesn't catch it, I am trying to  initialize phone.price with -225.25m.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you initialising with `Price` or `price` - Can you show your initialisation code

Comment: Are you initializing `this.price` or `this.Price`?

Comment: @user3248008: i have tested it with this value and it throws an exception, so i cannot reproduce your issue. Note that my backing field is private what it should be always. Otherwise it's possible to bypass the validation.

Comment: @user3248008: don't set the private backing field but use the property. So use `phone.Price` instead of `phone.price`. For this reason i prefix `_` before the backing field, otherwise it's not as clear as whether this is a property or field.

Answer (score 2):

The part `this.price` is the current value. You need to check the value that is passed in the setter using the `value` variable.

```
public decimal Price
{
    get 
    {
        { return this.price; }
    }
    set 
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The price should be positive!");
        }
        else
        {
            this.price = value;
        }

    }
}
```